# What characters are allowed by dojo's query function?

Tags: dojo

I plan to use dojo.query to get some elements by their name attribute from a page. However, since the value of name comes from the back-end, there might be some illegal characters, like `+`, `!=` and so on.

Is there a list of what characters are allowed? I plan to replace the invalid ones with "" via Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dojo will allow any valid HTML name

A name/id is valid html if:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Source: [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html)

Comment: oh, I mean the name attribute, like <div name="abc"></div>, I will get this element by dojo.query('div[name="abc"]'), but the name will have some illegal data(they come from back end.)

Comment: So from the HTML specs it follows that everything else than a letter for the first character and digits, hyphens, underscores, colons and periods are invalid

Comment: I just think maybe I just need to filter the non-alphanumeric character. Just curious about which are the illigal part :)

Comment: I think it is better to reverse the filter; only accept legal characters because those are very limited as pointed out above.